# How to deal with 401s in React application?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, design-patterns, react-router

I am creating a `react` SPA application and I am using tokens that are refreshed on every request to any authenticated route.

On `401`/`Unauthrorized` for any of these `AJAX` requests, I prompt the user with a popup/modal that requests the user to login so that they don't have to lose the state of their current page.

I could redirect them to the login page and then back but they would lose any current state unless I persisted it somehow, but that seems like unnecessary complexity.

The problem is that after the initial failed `AJAX` request, more AJAX requests could occur. So if I just redo the initial failed `AJAX` request then it will not be correct. I'm thinking that I could save all the failed request promises and then re-resolve them after the user has re-authenticated.

Is the proper high level approach?

Comment: I am using axios' interceptors to handle 401 and show login box, but I never considered multiple 401's. I think it could work for multiple requests as well.

Comment: Are you redirecting them to the main login page or using a popup/modal and then allowing them to keep on doing what they were doing without redirecting them in the first place? I'm talking about the latter.

Comment: yep, me too. I'm showing a popup. But I didn't try to handle multiple 401s - this is the difference.